# Azure kubernetes - python to read configmap?

Tags: python, azure, kubernetes, configmap

I am trying to Dockerize the python application and want to read the configuration settings from the configmap. How do I read configmap in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a configMap with the configuration file:

```
$ kubectl create configmap my-config --from-file my-config.file
```

Mount the configMap in your Pod's container and use it from your application:

```yaml
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: "/config-directory/my-config.file"
          subPath: "my-config.file"
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: my-config
```

Now, your config file will be available in `/config-directory/my-config.file`. You can read it from your Python code like below:

```
config = open("/config-directory/my-config.file", "r")
```

You can also use configMap's data as the container's env - [Define container environment variables using configMap data](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data)

```
config = os.environ['MY_CONFIG']
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I read this config file in python?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVijayakumar same way you read file from a local directory or environment variables.

Comment: @KamolHasan can you please help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66450175/unable-to-mount-the-config-file-using-configmap-on-a-pod-running-sparkapplicatio

Answer (score 2):

When creating an app for Kubernetes, it is good to follow the [The Twelve Factor App principles](https://12factor.net/). There is one item about [Config](https://12factor.net/config) that recommends to store environment specific app settings as *environment variables*.

In Python environment variables can be read with [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ), example:

```
import os
print(os.environ['DATABASE_HOST'])
print(os.environ['DATABASE_USER'])
```

And you can create those environment variables using `kubectl` with:

```
kubectl create configmap db-settings --from-literal=DATABASE_HOST=example.com,DATABASE_USER=dbuser
```

I would recommend to handle your environment settings with `kubectl kustomize` as described in [Declarative Management of Kubernetes Objects Using Kustomize](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/), especially with the [configmapGenerator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/#configmapgenerator) and apply them to different environments with:

```
kubectl apply -k <environment>/
```